# How to add the option that checks if checkbox is checked and deletes checked objects in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

Hello I'm a new comer to Django. I'm confused now having the thought of how django admin panel deleting option works and how to use that option in my site.The purpose is to use all CRUD options in one template not just with url like deleting one by one.

I have a models.py:

```
GRADES = (
    ('1', '1',), ('2', '2',),
    ('3', '3',), ('4', '4',),
    ('5', '5',), ('6', '6',),
    ('7', '7',), ('8', '8',),
    ('9', '9',), ('10', '10',),
    ('11', '11',),
)


class Grade(models.Model):
    grade = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=200,
                         choices=GRADES, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.grade


class Unique_grade(models.Model):

    grades = models.ForeignKey(
        Grade,
        null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        verbose_name="Sinf raqamini kiriting",

    )

    A_B_C = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True,)
    motto = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True,
                         verbose_name='Shior', blank=True,
                         unique=True, default=None)


    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['grades', 'A_B_C']

    def clean_motto(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['motto'] == "":
            return None
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data['motto']

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.grades}-{self.A_B_C}"


class Pupil(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(
        null=True)
    nation = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, null=True, verbose_name="Nation")
    grade = models.ForeignKey(Unique_grade, null=True,
                          on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    m_full_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, null=True, verbose_name="Mother's full name")
    f_full_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, null=True, verbose_name="Father's full name")
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [
             ['first_name', 'date_of_birth',
             'surname', 'nation',
             'grade', 'm_full_name',
             'f_full_name'],
        ]

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.first_name} {self.surname}."
```

my forms.py:

```
class CreateUniqueGrade(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Unique_grade
        fields = "__all__"
        error_messages = {
            NON_FIELD_ERRORS: {
                'unique_together': "Bunday sinf mavjud!",
            },

        }
    def clean_motto(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['motto'] == "":
            return None
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data['motto']
```

my views.py:

```
from .models import *
from .forms import CreateUniqueGrade

from datetime import date
current_year = date.today().year


grade_nums = Grade.objects.all()
unique_grades = Unique_grade.objects.all()


def home(request):
    content = {'grades': grade_nums, 'unique_grades': unique_grades,
            'current_year': current_year}
    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html/', content)


def grades(request, g):
    # grades = Grade.objects.all()
    cform = CreateUniqueGrade()

    if request.method == "POST":
        cform = CreateUniqueGrade(request.POST)
        if cform.is_valid():
            cform.save()
            return redirect(f'/grades/{g}')
    uni = Unique_grade.objects.all().get(id=g)


    unique_grade = Unique_grade.objects.all()
    content = {
        'grade': unique_grade.filter(grades=g),
        'grades': grade_nums,
        'unique_grades': unique_grades,
        'current_year': current_year,
        'g': g,
        'Unique': cform,

    }

    return render(request, 'accounts/grades.html/', content)


def pupils(request, g, p):

    pupil = Pupil.objects.all()
    content = {
        'pupil': pupil.filter(grade_id=p),
        'grades': grade_nums,
        'unique_grades': unique_grades,
        'current_year': current_year
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/pupils.html/', content)


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/about.html/', {'grades': grade_nums, 'unique_grades': unique_grades, 'current_year': current_year})


def for_each_pupil(request, g, p, for_each):
    pupil = Pupil.objects.all()

    content = {'pupil': pupil.get(id=for_each), 'grades': grade_nums,
                                'unique_grades': unique_grades, 'current_year': current_year}
    return render(request, 'accounts/for_each_pupil.html/', content)
```

finally my template:

```
    {% extends 'accounts/maktab.html' %} {% load static %} {% block content %}
<!-- css > sinflar.css -->

<h3 id="to_top"></h3>
{% include "accounts/special_icons/plus-minus.html" %}
<div class="row">
    {% for i in grade %}
    <div class="pupil">
        <div class="first fir">
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <input type="checkbox" name="todelete" value="{{ i.id }}">
            </form>
            <img src="#" alt="#" />
        </div>
        <div class="second sec">
            <div>
                <a
                    href="{% url 'pupils' i.grades i.id %}"
                    style="text-decoration: none; color: aliceblue;"
                >
                    <h3 class="is_m">{{i}} sinfi</h3>
                    {% if i.motto %}
                    <h3>Shior: {{i.motto}}</h3>
                    {% endif %}
                </a>
            </div>
            <button class="shr" onclick="forShrink()">shrink</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% empty %}
    <h2>
        Apologies...<br />
        But you have no unique grades yet.
    </h2>

    {% endfor %}

    <div class="pupil pup remove" >
        <div class="first fir">
            <img src="#" alt="#" id="for_ease"/>
        </div>
        <div class="second">
            <form action="" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %} {% if Unique.non_field_errors %}
                <style>
                    .remove {
                        opacity: 1;
                        height: 600px;
                        position: relative;
                        pointer-events: all;
                    }
                </style>
                {{ Unique.non_field_errors }} {% endif %}

                <div class="field nums def">
                    {{ Unique.grades.errors }}
                    <label for="{{ Unique.grades.id_for_label }}"
                        >Sinf raqami</label
                    >
                    {{ Unique.grades }}
                </div>
                <div class="field letters def">
                    <h3>Sinf raqami: {{ g }}</h3>

                    <label for="{{ Unique.A_B_C.id_for_label }}"
                        >Sinf Belgisi</label
                    >
                    {{ Unique.A_B_C }}
                </div>

                <div class="field motto">
                    {% if Unique.motto.errors %}
                    <style>
                        .remove {
                            opacity: 1;
                            height: 600px;
                            position: relative;
                            pointer-events: all;
                        }
                    </style>
                    {{ Unique.motto.errors }} {% endif %}
                    <label for="{{ Unique.motto.id_for_label }}"
                        >motto</label
                    >
                    {{ Unique.motto }}
                </div>
                <button type="submit" name="submit" id="subm">
                    Add
                </button>
                <br />
                <button id="subm">
                    <a
                        href="#to_top"
                        style="text-decoration: none; color: aliceblue;"
                        onclick="remove()"
                        >Cancel</a
                    >
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    selectElement("id_grades", "{{ g }}");

    function selectElement(id, valueToSelect) {
        let element = document.getElementById(id);
        element.value = valueToSelect;
    }
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

And again main purpose is to have all CRUD in one template without url routing for each object.
Second is to have 'delete by check' option.

Please if you know the answer don't keep silence. Would be very glad! Thanks!